# how to reject the submitted binary from new Itunes interface

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, app-store-connect

> I just submitted the `iOS` build to apple after that I realized,
>   there is something wrong and want to remove the existing binary and
>   re-submit the new one. I think today `Apple` has changed their itunes
>   interface. Any one knows then, please share it here.

when I try to submit the binary from Xcode 5.1.1 it shows the following error. Since I need to reject the existing one.

[image]

Comment: Did your original upload fail to iTunes Connect? Mine this morning did, I have a feeling it is more of an Apple issue than anything else. Trying to work out some common ground

Answer (score 1):

In new itunes connect, You can reject your binary from here

[image]

Comment: Actually, my app status is not in review state even though after submit the app itunes says waiting for upload. So, i do not know what to do now. Because of this ituens not shows the option to reject the binary but when it shows the app when i click the add "+" button.

Comment: @loganathan Lot of people are experiencing the same issue. I guess this is a bug in new iTunes connect UI. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681089/waiting-for-upload-status-issue-in-new-itune-connect-site)