# New UI - How to reject New release version which is in "Waiting for review" status?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

i uploaded new version of iPhone app using Application Loader.
and this version is in "Waiting for review" Status but i got some bug on that so i need to reject that version and re-Upload it.

i didn't find how to reject new version in [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/) New UI.

Comment: See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683746/how-to-reject-the-submitted-binary-from-new-itunes-interface/25684105#25684105 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678723/reject-this-binary-in-new-itunes-connect-ui

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes connect, go into
    •   'Manage Your Applications' then click your application. Then
    •   'View details' and press
    •   'Binary Details' under 'Links'. You'll see the
    •   'Reject this binary' in the upper right corner.